# VBA code won't write array to range, only it's first element

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I need to do the following:

- lift the range C2:AU264 into an 2D array
- create another 1D array, (1 To 11880)
- fill second array with values from the first one ("transpose")
- write array 2 back to the sheet

Here is the code I am using:

```
Private Ws As Worksheet
Private budgets() As Variant
Private arrayToWrite() As Variant
Private lastrow As Long
Private lastcol As Long

Private Sub procedure()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set Ws = Sheet19
Ws.Activate

lastrow = Ws.Cells.Find("*", searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).row
lastcol = Ws.Cells.Find("*", searchorder:=xlByColumns, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Column

ReDim budgets(1 To lastrow - 1, 1 To lastcol - 2)
budgets= Ws.Range("C2:AU265")

ReDim arrayToWrite(1 To (lastCol - 2) * (lastRow - 1))

k = 0
For j = 1 To UBound(budgets, 2)
    For i = 1 To UBound(budgets, 1)
      arrayToWrite(i + k) = budgets(i, j)
    Next i
    k = k + lastrow - 1
Next j


Set Ws = Sheet6
Ws.Activate

Ws.Range("E2").Resize(UBound(arrayToWrite)).Value = arrayToWrite


'For i = 1 To UBound(arrayToWrite)
    'Ws.Range(Cells(i + 1, 5).Address).Value = arrayToWrite(i)
'Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

This just writes the first value from the range C2:AU264 (the first element of the first array) through the whole range E2:E11881. If however, I un-comment the For loop just before the end of my script and do it that way, it does work, but is slow. How can I write the array correctly using the first statement?

Comment: I think the length of range is different than what you're writing. I believe it should be Resize(UBound(arrayToWrite)+1).

Comment: Charlie, I don't think that is the problem. Isn't "normal" VB behavior in sich a case that everything after the boundary gets cut off? I that case I would only lose the last value but I can't get anything! Just the first valueof  array budget(1,1) gets written through all the rows

Comment: I agree - I knew there was some issue if the range doesn't match the array - looks like someone caught it below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to write an array to a range, the array must have two dimensions. Even if you only wish to write a single column.

Change

```
ReDim arrayToWrite(1 To (lastCol - 2) * (lastRow - 1))
```

to

```
ReDim arrayToWrite(1 To (lastCol - 2) * (lastRow - 1), 1 To 1)
```

and

```
arrayToWrite(i + k) = budgets(i, j)
```

to

```
arrayToWrite(i + k, 1) = budgets(i, j)
```

Comment: you should note that writing in a single row, having a only one dimension works. `[A1:B1] = Array(1, 2)` does exactly what it looks like ;)

Answer (score 2):

simply use transpose... change

```
Ws.Range("E2").Resize(UBound(arrayToWrite)).Value = arrayToWrite
```

to

```
Ws.Range("E2").Resize(UBound(arrayToWrite)).Value = Application.Transpose(arrayToWrite)
```

Hint: there is no need for `ReDim budgets(1 To lastrow - 1, 1 To lastcol - 2)`.
If `budgets` is a variant then `budgets = Ws.Range("C2:AU265")` will automatically set the ranges (upper left cell (in this case C2) will be `(1, 1)`).

**EDIT**

Assuming you only want to write down all columns (one after another) below each other, you can shorten the macro a bit like that:

```
Private Sub procedure()

  Dim inArr As Variant, outArr() As Variant
  Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long

  With Sheet19
    .Activate
    inArr = .Range(, .Cells(2, 3), .Cells(.Cells.Find("*", , , , 1, 2).Row, .Cells.Find("*", , , , 2, 2).Column)).Value
  End With

  ReDim outArr(1 To UBound(inArr) * UBound(inArr, 2))
  k = 1

  For j = 1 To UBound(inArr, 2)
    For i = 1 To UBound(inArr)
      k = k + 1
      arrayToWrite(k) = budgets(i, j)
    Next i
  Next j

  Sheet6.Range("E2:E" & UBound(arrayToWrite)).Value = Application.Transpose(arrayToWrite)

End Sub
```

And if you want each row transposed and below each other than simply switch the two `For...`-lines. (Still the code does basically the same like before)

Comment: Dirk, thank you for your reply! I can't believe how stupid I was - the arrayToWrite "stretches" in the direction of rows and not columns! That's why It kept getting only the first value. I understand your solution, but also, could I have done it by assigning values to this array differently in the first place? ( arrayToWrite(i + k) = budgets(i, j) )

Comment: no... a 1d-array will always "stretch" by columns (1 row height). To use it without transpose, you need a second dimension like @jkpieterse showed pretty well ;)

Comment: In that case we misunderstood each other. I thought it stretched by columns, thats why I sorted my code like that. Ok thanks ;)